# How to persist entities in the received order in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Assume you have an entity, `Post`, where the data is received from a remote server in the following order:

```
Post 93
Post 42 // meaning of life, heh :)
Post 53
Post 100
Post 6
```

What is the best way to persist this data to disk in the order received so that it can be fetched again in the same order later when the user is offline? Keep in mind that the posts returned will be ever changing, with some objects being removed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to achieve what you want.

1) Make an Entity, e.g. PostsFromServer, add one-to-many relationship, e.g.. called posts. Choose the relationship to be order. This order will automatically be the same your sequence input of post.

[image]

2) without using relationship, you add an idNumber attribute to Post entity. This idNumber is representing the sequence of input of Post. You have another entity called currentIdNumber, storing the next idNumber for the coming Post. Before a Post is input into DB, read currentIdNumber and put the value into the idNumber attribute. Then increment the currentIdNumber by 1. Then When you fetch the Post entity, use idNumber in sortDescriptor to sort the order of array return.

[image]

Good luck

Comment: Right now I'm using the separate entity as you mentioned in option one, but there are many unforeseen caveats that I've run into that I'm writing hacks around (which I don't exactly want to have to do).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are receiving these posts asynchronously, I recommend a thread-safe queue. Enqueue each post as it arrives and have a separate thread in charge of processing the queue.